# Flex 4.5.1 and iOS, Android development 

Tags: android, ios, flash, apache-flex, mobile

I recently came across Flex builder and it was gr8 to know that it supports iOS, Android and Blackberry Tablet OS development all within same IDE, framework and api. This is awesome!!!

The project I am assigned is a kind of large product and in its desktop versions we have used core C++ and OS API for development (i.e. WIN 32 ), So before starting the development I am instructed to perform a detailed feasibility study on Flex 4.5.1. I have been reading various blogs and posts related to this and now I have kind of mixed opinion for it.

The app that is planned to be developed will be dealing with OS specific tasks i.e. start the camera, record a call, provide various sharing options etc. I want to know is it possible with Flex 4.5.1 or developing with OS specific SDK is must..?

As I said it is a large product is there any other development platform available which can target at least iOS and Android if not BlackBerry ?

Any tutorial/ blog post related to Flex 4.5.1 mobile development or its alternatives will be also quite helpful..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Regarding alternatives, perhaps Appcelerator Titanium can be one, if you are OK with developing in JavaScript. Basically, with Titanium you develop against native APIs, using JavaScript, and then compile to native apps. Currently it supports iOS and Android. http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex mobile 3 have a new exciting feature the "modules extensions" they are like libraries that let you use native code from air mobile. so in principle nothing is imposible. You can get some modules extensions from [here](https://github.com/patrickkulling/Air-Mobile-Extensions).

Unfortunately, Flex Mobile is kind of dead... see [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2011/11/flash-focus.html) note from Adobe.

If you look for alternatives you have [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) (an html wrapper, that allow to create a native application from html and use the native api from JavaScript) or [AppCeleator](http://www.appcelerator.com/).

Comment: -1 For misinformation about flex for mobile. It is very much alive since ONLY development of the Flash Player Runtime for `browsers` on mobile devices will be limited to support and bugfixes. The flex SDK will become an apache project and is not put there to just die.

Comment: Nice to know! Air mobile is a great language :)