# Flex and Action Scripts

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile

I'm instructed to develop a project in such a way that it is available for iOS, Android and Blackberry OS platform all at once. **A herculean task!! indeed...**

I am searching for all the possible development platforms for this assignment. I came across Flex 4.5.1 and the initial thoughts are really positive. Somewhere in SO I read that flex applications suffer from code bloating problem. I dont want such solution; infact memory is an important concern for me.

I want to know which one of the following is the optimum approach:

1. Developing using OS specific SDK i.e. xCode for iPhone, Andriod SDK for Android.
2. Developing using Flex builder and ignore code bloating.
3. Using Flash Builder and developing application in ActionScript.

I would also love to know if there is any other platform / language / API available for me...

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Can i write C / C++ code inside inside flex development... if Yes than where I can learn doing that....

Comment: Adobe Alchemy enables C / C++ code to be compiled to ActionScript 3.0 as a SWF or SWC that runs on Adobe Flash Player 10 or Adobe AIR 1.5  http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex 4.5.1 and iOS, Android development ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223296/flex-4-5-1-and-ios-android-development)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash Player's ubiquitous delivery makes developing and packaging mobile applications easy; however, HTML5 / JavaScript platforms such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) would also enable rapid cross platform delivery.

Flex is heavier than Pure ActionScript.  Depending on what you're developing, Flash Professional or a pure ActionScript project in Flash Builder may meet needs in a very lean and performant manner.

Comment: I am developing an application which ll provide audio, video chatting real time sharing... My application will be used by some other applications which may not be in Flash...ur suggestions ?

Comment: Flash as pure ActionScript would handle those needs.  Other applications could embed your Flash content.

Comment: ok thanks... now final question where I can learn ActionScripts... what actually are they ?

Comment: ActionScript is ECMAScript 262 edition 3, very similar to JavaScript.  Maybe starting with docs at Adobe Developer Connection http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/as3.html such as Object Oriented Programming http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html or just post questions here for functional areas of your app.

Answer (score 2):

few days back I also asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223296/flex-4-5-1-and-ios-android-development) on SO and unfortunately so far I have not got the answer I wanted. (question is still open and you can share your findings with me there..)

Regarding your questions about Flex 4.5.1, I would like to say it is very neat and nearly perfect programming platform and learning it is quite simple. The Support & training  available from Adobe is just awesome. You can easily get confidence in just few weeks. See an [Excellent Downloadable tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html), I would suggest you follow it for initial weeks.

In Flex, We Program in *.mxml files and ActionScripts(*.as) ... *.mxml files are converted to ActionScript during compilation. To increase the efficiency you can directly program in ActionScripts once you understand how they actually work. (Which I am trying to learn now.)

I am not sure about C/ C++ but Flex definitely supports some other languages i.e. Java, PHP etc. For Java developers like me another surprisingly good thing is that Flex can be integrated with Spring  also.

Share your findings about Flex..

Answer (score 1):

There are a quite a few cross platform mobile development tools

phoneGap

Appcelerator

Rho mobile

Mosync

Sencha

Corona

WidgetPad

Each one has their own advantages and disadvantages. For example, the applications built using phoneGap uses a html view to show the UI while Appcelerator uses native UI components which offers better UI responsiveness. Some are free and some are not. So you need to decide on your requirements and choose a framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you like HTML5/JavaScript and want to extend it with C++ then you should try MoSync, it gives you the flexibility to blend them all if you so like. You can find out more at mosync.com.